# Opencart product Image in order confirmation email

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to make the images of ordered products appear in the customer order confirmation mail sent after checkout. The content of that email is in the order.tpl file and contains such things as $product['name'] for product name, $product['model'] for product model. I don't know what variable/array holds the product image or how to implement this.

Comment: The email is being sent from `model/checkout/order.php/addOrderHistory()`. You will have to modify it a bit.

Comment: You need to create a modification for the code in the above post mentioned files. Also you would need to add reading the image from database because it is not included there in the default Version. So yes. You would need to modify it a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to modify `model/checkout/order/addOrderHistory()` function. Please note that products of any order are fetched from `order_product` table. And it doesn't contain any image field. To do so you have to create a functionality which fetches product image from the `product` table and then process that image to do further.

For example, create any function in `catalog/model/order` file. like...

```
public function getProductImage($product_id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `image` FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product` WHERE product_id = '".(int)$product_id."'");

    if ($query->row) {
        return $query->row['image'];
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Call this method in `foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $product) {` loop like

`$product_image = $this->getProductImage($product['product_id'])`.

Then in the same loop resize the image by checking

```
$this->load->model('tool/image');

if ($product_image) {
   $product_image = $this->model_tool_resize($product_image, width, height);
}
```

And in your product array just add this,

```
$data['products'][] = array(
 'image' => $product_image,
 .....
);
```

And in your `.tpl` file check

```
if ($product['image']){
  your design to display image
}
```

That's It.

Comment: I thought this should work, I made some edits to the order.php page, here is the pastebin link : http://pastebin.com/gMDqpvsw  but I get an internal server error on checkout page, may be I didn't do the edits in the right places, help look into it, thank you, edits from line 538.

Answer (score 1):

The email is being sent from `model/checkout/order.php/addOrderHistory()`. You will have to add your image in the product loop. Then in the `.tpl` file, you will have to insert new column and display the product image inside it.

Comment: Thanks, we are almost there. Is the product image variable already available, how is it named?

Comment: You will have to see if it is available or not. If not, you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

the variable you are looking for is image
use it as below.

```
<?php echo $product['image']; ?>
```

you can find free extensions on opencart site.